# Why does the position of braces in JavaScript matter?

Tags: javascript

Consider these two functions.

```
function func1() {
   return
   {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}

function func2() {
   return {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}
```

`alert(typeof func2()) //return object`

`alert(typeof func1()) //return undefined`

Why does the position of the braces matter when in many other languages it does not? Is it a language feature or a bug?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because of [automatic semicolon insertion](http://jamesallardice.com/understanding-automatic-semi-colon-insertion-in-javascript/). The first code is the same as

```
function func1() {
   return;
   {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}
```

If you wonder why this code doesn't produce a syntax error, `foo:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Regarding

> Is it a language feature or a bug?

It's a feature. But a very dangerous one. The best way to keep it being a feature for you is to stick to consistent formatting style (I'd suggest to use the [Google style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) until you're experienced enough to make your own).

Comment: This would be improved by a link to [12.9 The return Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) that [Ejay pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120708/why-does-the-position-of-braces-in-javascript-matter#comment37213016_24120708).